# RowDataBound not acting the way I expect

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a Gridview with an ImageButton that should become visible for the selected row only. I'm doing this in the OnRowDataBound event, but it doesn't work.

```
protected void OnRowDataBoundMS(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) > 0)
        {
            // some working code that handles the edit mode
        }
        else if (Gridview1.SelectedValue != null)
        {
            ImageButton ImgBut1 = e.Row.FindControl("ButtonUp") as ImageButton;
            ImgBut1.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

My gridview looks like this:

```
    <asp:GridView runat="server"
                  ID="Gridview1"
                  DataSourceID="Milestones"
                  DataKeyNames="ID"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                  OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing"
                  OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBoundMS"
                  OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChangedMS">
    ...
        <asp:templatefield HeaderText="Order" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="ButtonUp" runat="server" OnClick ="OrderUp"  ImageUrl="img/up.png" Visible="false"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:templatefield>
```

I spent the last 3 hours on this and I start to freak out. Any hints on this? Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The other alternative is to use the [SelectedIndexChanged event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedindexchanged(v=vs.110).aspx) if you are using the Select command option:

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChangedMS(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        Control ctl = row.FindControl("ButtonUp");
        ctl.Visible = (row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Selected) != 0;
    }
}
```

Something like that; RowDataBound may fire before the selected index gets updated (not sure about that...).

Comment: Doing it in the `SelectedIndexChanged` is more efficient than my answer. However, I would like to suggest an edit to your answer (but I am afraid that my edit may apply without your approval).

Comment: Edits are versioned on SO so you can see the original and edit, so edit away :-)

Comment: Thanks for the hint on your doubt on the RowDataBound firing earlier than the selected index gets updated.

Comment: @Barnabeck - Did you try the exact code given in this answer or did you also call `GridView.DataBind`? This answer works for me as long as I don't call `DataBind` (as a result, `RowDataBound` is not triggered at all in the process).

Comment: I hadn't tried your edited code actually; by the time I checked the posted solutions Brians code was incomplete, giving just the idea he was aiming at and on his initial idea I developed my solution. Your code works fine for me, too! I will mark it as the answer, though I don't know what then will happen to the solution I posted. Stackoverflow's user rules are sometimes irritating to me; and I don't know if they allow 2 solutions

Comment: @Barnabeck unfortunately you have to choose 1 but it's useful to have a comment like you have indicating both work.

Comment: If you don't want to have to make another database call, using looping works - this essentially hides all the other buttons and reloads them.  The reason why @Barnabeck your code works with Databind() is that method destroys the controls in the grid and rebinds - the approach above refreshes the button control state without having to hit the database again (which is fine, but helpful not to have to do if none of the data is actually changing).

Answer (score 2):

You can detect the selected row in the `RowDataBound` event handler with the `RowState` property, the same way you detect the edit row:

```
if ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Selected) != 0)
{
    ...
}
```

An alternative is to set the `Visible` property of the ImageButton in the markup, with a data-binding expression:

```
<asp:ImageButton runat="server" Visible='<%# ((Container as GridViewRow).RowState & DataControlRowState.Selected) != 0 %>' ... />
```

Note: make sure that you call `GridView1.DataBind()` in the `SelectedIndexChanged` event handler, in order to refresh the content of the GridView.

Comment: Thank you, I tried both alternatives which sound convincing to me, but they wouldn't work. Most likely because the RowDataBound firing earlier as Brian said.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the key comment is what Brian Mains said about the RowDataBound firing before the selected Index gets updated. I can't prove this to be generally right, but it seems so. Therefore all attempts, even following ConnersFan suggestions didn't worked out. I did what Brian suggested and used the SelectedIndexChanged event handler, but without looping through all rows. The solution is actually quite simple:

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChangedMS(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Gridview1.DataBind();
    ImageButton ImgBut1 = Gridview1.SelectedRow.FindControl("ButtonUp") as ImageButton;
    ImgBut1.Visible = true;
}
```